expo-camera webapp can only capture images in 640x480 resolution
Using expo-camera in a mobile browser (Chrome 127 & 128 and Firefox 127) to take pictures always results in image resolution 640 x 480, despite setting either the pictureSize prop or the quality=1 option to takePictureAsync.
Using expo-camera via Expo on Android or iOS works as expected & I am able to select & change the resolution of a captured image via the 'pictureSize' prop.
const takePicture = async () => {
  if (!cameraRef.current) return;
        try {
    const sizes = await cameraRef.current.getAvailablePictureSizesAsync();
    console.log('Available sizes:', sizes);
    console.log('Platform:', Platform.OS);

      const options = {
        quality: 1,
        imageType: 'png',
        skipProcessing: false,
        exif: true,
      };
    const { uri } = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);

          Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {
      console.log(`Saved image size: width = ${width}, height = ${height}`);
        });
    setCapturedPhotos((prevPhotos) => [...prevPhotos, uri]);
    console.log(store);
        } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error taking picture:', error);
        }
};

const renderCameraView = () => (
    <CameraView
      style={styles.camera}
      type={facing}
      ref={cameraRef}
      //pictureSize="2160x3840" // android requires height x width while ios works with width x height
    >
      <View style={styles.bottomButtonsContainer}>
        <Pressable style={styles.captureButton} onPress={takePicture} />
      </View>
      <View style={[
        styles.overlayContainer,
        overlaySide === 'left' ? styles.overlayLeft : styles.overlayRight
        ]}>
        {capturedPhotos.length > 0 && PreviousImageOverlay({ capturedPhotos })}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.topLeftContainer}>
        {capturedPhotos.length > 0 && ImageThumbnails({ capturedPhotos })}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.actionButtonsContainer}>
        {capturedPhotos.length > 0 && renderActionButtons()}
      </View>
    </CameraView>
  )

Dependencies:
"expo": "^51.0.31",
"expo-camera": "^15.0.15"
"react-native": "0.74.3"
Tried changing pictureSize prop to any of the available via
const sizes = await cameraRef.current.getAvailablePictureSizesAsync();
console.log('Available sizes:', sizes);

